# how can i make sure that FIREWALL is not stopping MYSQL

Tags: mysql, networking, firewall

I am able to access MYSQL using the command Line tool , but somehow i could not able to access MYSQL Databse using Liferay .

During the server start u it says that Connection Refused .

Now my question is that , how can i make sure that FIREWALL is not stopping it ??

I am using WIndows XP  MYSQL 5.1  coulld anybody please let me know this .

Thanks

Comment: I've marked your question for closure since its better suited for serverfault.com

Comment: Check that the mysql user has the privileges to connect mysql from remote hosts.

Comment: Seems something i am not sure  , could you please let me know how can i check this ??(privileges to connect mysql from remote hosts.)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add an exception to the firewall list
2. To make sure that your firewall is restricting it, try disabling the firewall once and then use the service and verify if Connection is accepted.

Comment: For using Database with Liferay , its specifying it inside a portal-ext.properties file ( A file inside server ) , so there is no concept of Exceptions , try , catch here .